# Moisture evaporation from paper

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, water, estimation, evaporation

Is there a way to calculate moisture loss from a piece of paper in contact with a heat source.

If you have roll of paper 1 meter wide of infinite length the paper weight is 130g paper per m2 with 8% moisture going over a heat contact point of 120 degrees c for 20 meters and the paper is travelling at 200meters per min, what is the moisture loss?

What would be the equation to calculate different variables?

Answer (score 2):

The Key variable is the Latent heat (Enthalpy) of water evaporation - $L$.

Each segment of $dx$ of the paper stays on the hot plate for $t = \frac{20m}{200m/min} = 6s$. In that $6s$ the paper+water heats up to $100^0C$ and the rest of the heat power goes to evaporating it.

You still need to figure out the power delivered to the paper (depends on the thermal conductivity of paper, thickness ect.)

$$ P\Delta t = Lm_{evaporated} + (c_{paper}M_{paper}+c_{water}m_{water}) \Delta T $$

Comment: Thermal conductivity is 0.33